# How do you add a transform to the Meteor.users Collection?

Tags: meteor

How do you add a transform to the Meteor.users Collection?

I've tried: `Users = new Meteor.Collection 'users'` but this breaks Meteor since the collection already exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to hack it at least.

There is a _transform property attached to the Meteor.users collection just like all the other collections.

Just do:

```
Meteor.users._transform = function(user) { 
  // attach methods, instantiate a user class, etc.
  // return the object
}
```

to hook it up! Cool!

Comment: That seems to work, but I think it might lead to trouble later. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/810. Internal Meteor code assumes users are NOT transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like using _transform could cause issues and it's safer to use a wrapper unfortunately both are a bit hacky.

Source and more details: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/810#issuecomment-15069258